# How do I sync my Google Calendar and my iCloud Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, icloud

Each is currently synced effectively with my iCal app. So the breakdown looks like this:

Google Calendar <==> iCal (on MacBook)
iCal (MacBook) <==> iCloud Calendar
iCloud < ≠ > Google

How should I edit my settings to enable entries made in Google Calendar and iCloud Calendar appear in each other?

Answer (score 1):

Answer according to Google depends upon the version of ical you are running:

https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/99358?hl=en

> **Versions 3.x-4.x**
>
> To set up CalDAV support for Google Calendar in Apple's iCal, follow
>   these steps:
>
> Open Apple iCal, go to Preferences and then the Accounts tab. Click on
>   the + button to add an account. In the box that pops up, enter a
>   description for the account and your Google Account username and
>   password. Under Server Options, add the following URL:
>
> `https://www.google.com/calendar/dav/YOUREMAIL@DOMAIN.COM/user`
>
> Replace 'YOUREMAIL@DOMAIN.COM' with the email address that you use to
>   log in to Calendar. Make sure to include the '@domain.com' portion
>   (which is @gmail.com for Gmail users) in this section. DO NOT
>   substitute your username for 'user' at the end of the URL. Leave the
>   Use Kerberos v5 for authentication option unchecked. Click Add. Under
>   the Delegation tab, select the calendars you'd like to add to iCal by
>   checking the boxes next to them. You may need to hit refresh to get
>   the latest list of calendars. Add your email address to your Address
>   Book card by selecting Add Email. You'll be prompted to add your email
>   address only if your address is not already in your Address Book.
>
> **Versions 5.x and up**
>
> Open Apple iCal In the toolbar, click Calendar, then Preferences Click
>   the Accounts tab In the accounts pane on the left, click the + button
>   to add an account  Enter the following information: Account Type:
>   Google Email Address: Enter the email address that you use to log in
>   to Calendar. Make sure to include the '@domain.com' portion (which is
>   @gmail.com for Gmail users) in this section. Password: Enter the
>   password for the email address you listed above.

Answer (score 0):

I understand, I also had this problem when I first bought an iPhone, but I've been using it for a very long time and have figured it all out so much that I can't use other phones. However, if you run into this problem, you may get different errors. https://backlightblog.com/icloud-storage-full go here to see how to fix it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/147031)